# Exporting image and text data to RTF file in Python

Tags: python-3.x, image, text, rtf

I am doing a task that involves quite a few images and text data and I need to write them into an RTF file in Python. 
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Using Spyder-iPython, print your text and plot all your graphs and images; then, right-click from the console where the text and graphs are and do Save As HTML/XML (select inline). Everything will be exported as an HTML file that you can load with any text editor, MS Word, LibreOffice Writer, etc.

Enjoy!